# Can you dynamically change properties of node-RED nodes

Tags: mqtt, node-red, lorawan

I'm currently working on an application that uses MQTT to communicate between an android app and a LoRaWAN gateway. It uses node-RED on the gateway's side.

I can manually set up on what topic my MQTT output node publishes to. I was wondering if there was a way to make this property of the node change depending on the message it receives.

For exemple, would it be possible to send a topic attribute alongside my msg and payload and use that value to set the property inside the node.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just leave the topic field blank in the mqtt-out node config and set the `msg.topic` property on the message to be the topic you want to publish that message to.

Comment: I just saw I could do that right before you answer. Thank you for confirming it!